# On changing limits of integration when there are domain problems.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

As an example say I have $$\int_{\pi/2}^\pi \frac{2}{1- \sin(2x)} dx$$

I would like to perform the substitution $2x = \arcsin(u)$ but I notice this would not be surjective on the interval given by the extremes of integration.

So, to solve the problem, I say instead of having the domain of $\sin(x)$ be $[0, 2 \pi]$ let it be $[3 \pi/2, 7 \pi/2]$ in this way $\arcsin(u)$ will take values in $[\pi, \pi/2]$.

But now performing the substitution I obtain

$$\int_{1}^{-1} \frac{1}{((1-u)(\sqrt{1-u^2})} du$$

That does not give the same values of the original integral that evaluates to $2$. Where is the mistake in my reasoning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your domain of integration should not extend to 1. Instead, work with
$\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/4}  \frac{2}{1 - \sin(2x)} dx+ \int_{3\pi/4}^{\pi}\frac{2}{1 - \sin(2x)} dx$ such that your substitution of arcsin is well-defined.

Given $x \in [\pi/2, 3\pi/4]$, we know that $\cos(2x)$ is non-positive, so it must be the case that $du = 2\cos(2x) dx = -2\sqrt{1 - \sin^2(2x)} dx = -2\sqrt{1 - u^2} dx$. I feel that this subtlety may have been neglected in your derivation.

Comment: Thank you very much, So I would obtain $ - \int_{-1}^{\sqrt{2}/2} \frac{1}{((1-u)(\sqrt{1-u^2})} du + \int_{\sqrt{2}/2}^{1} \frac{1}{((1-u)(\sqrt{1-u^2})} du $ correct? ( I am still having problems).

Comment: $-\int_{0}^{-1} \dfrac{du}{(1 - u)\sqrt{1 - u^2}} + \int_{-1}^{0} \dfrac{du}{(1 - u)\sqrt{1 - u^2}}$

Comment: How do you bypass the problem of $\arcsin$ not being defined between $\pi$ and $\pi /2$?

Comment: $\sin : [\pi/2, 5\pi/2] \rightarrow [-1,1]$ which is surjective, as that is necessary. Since it is not injective, we must consider partitions of the domain such that it is injective.